# svn+ssh: rewrite repository name

Tags: svn

I'm implementing a service which hosts Subversion repositories.  I need each repository to have a front-end name, which is what consumers of the service will use, and a back-end path, which is where the repository actually lives on the server's file system.  The mapping of name to path is stored in a database.  Repositories are accessed via ssh.

For example, the repo with a URL of `svn+ssh://server/my-repo` might actually live on the file system of `server` at `/srv/repos/some-random-string`.

When a Subversion client accesses `svn+ssh://server/my-repo`, it simply runs a command on the remote server via ssh - this command is `svnserve --tunnel` (or something along those lines).  The client and the svnserve process on the server communicate using [their own protocol](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_ra_svn/protocol), and the name of the repository is embedded in the protocol - in this case the name of the repository is `my-repo`.  `svnserve` then looks for `my-repo` in the current directory and serves it up.

The problem is that `my-repo` is the *front-end name*, which differs from the *back-end path*, which in this case is `/srv/repos/some-random-string`.  Looking in `/srv/repos` instead of the current directory is easy to do by forcing ssh to run `svnserve --root=/srv/repos --tunnel`, but mapping `my-repo` to `some-random-string` seems to require doing rewrites in the communications between client and server.

**Here is my question:** Is it possible to use libsvn to do the dirty work of parsing those communications and doing the appropriate rewrites?  Any pointers on where to start?